# ngOptions successfully refreshes with new values, but ng-model is not data-binding

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-ngmodel, ng-options, angularjs-digest

I have 2 select forms populated using `ng-options`, such as:

```
<select ng-options="item.id as product.category for product in products" ng-model="order.category" ng-change='find_brands(order.category)' ></select>
<select ng-options="brand.id as brand.name for brand in brands" ng-model="order.brand" ></select>
<button ng-click='Get_Products(order)>ORDER</button>
```

When the first dropdown is selected, it will trigger a `$http` call to populate the second dropdown like so:

```
$scope.find_brands = function(category){
  $http
    .get('Default.aspx/Find_Brands', {category: category})
    .success(data){$scope.products = data.d};
};
```

This correctly populates the `"brands"` dropdown with the new values. However, when I go to select a brand, the `ng-model` does not change. When tested, I receive a null value. I've looked into `$scope.$apply` to work with the `$digest` cycle, but it seems like that is not my problem (the `"brands"` dropdown successfully gets refreshed data, it just doesn't SEND data out).

Does anyone have an idea of whats going on and how to fix it?

Comment: I assume it's a typo in your question to assign `data.d` to `$scope.product` in your service. Also, `success` is deprecated for `then` so you might consider using that instead.

Comment: you populate products which populates both the category and the brands. which I am guessing is putting you in some kind of loop as the ng-change gets called again if the category is not present (why not populate just the brands) and can you console the order after clicking the ORDER button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been creating this simple example for you: http://jsbin.com/degece/edit?html,js,console,output

In your code there are some errors.

In this line **you use item.id instead product.id**

```
<select ng-options="item.id as product.category for product in products" ng-model="order.category" ng-change='find_brands(order.category)' ></select>
```

In this you have a **quote typo**, you don't need the quote before Get_Products

```
<button ng-click='Get_Products(order)>ORDER</button>
```

Finally, here you need to **assign the result of the call to the $scope.brands** variable

```
.success(data){$scope.products = data.d};
```

In my example you can see some best practice implementations like the model initialization.

Comment: You're welcome! You can ask me anything if you need something else ;)